# Best way to create a "link" method in Rails (model or helper)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I've done a lot of research on this topic and there seems to be some dispute, so I wanted to get your opinions. Here is my basic situation - I have a User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # User consists of first_name, last_name, and other fields
  has_one :profile # 1-1 mapping between User and Profile
                   # Profile is a nested resource of User

  # this is the method up for debate:
  # this obviously doesn't work unless I include
  # the necessary modules in this class
  def link(*args)
    link_to self.first_name, users_profile_path(self), args
  end
end
```

My reasoning for this kind of behavior is that, in my views, I'd like to do something like:

```
<%= @user.link %>
```

instead of:

```
<%= link_to @user.name, users_profile_path(@user) ... %>
```

every time. This link will be used thousands of times, in many different views. I want to centralize this "method" so that, when I need to make a change, I can make it once.

However, this practice absolutely violates the MVC architecture. Others suggest using a helper:

```
module UsersHelper
  def profile_link(user, *args)
    link_to user.name, users_profile_path(user), args
  end
end
```

Now, I have to wrap the user in the method instead of calling it as a method ON user:

```
<%= profile_link(@user) %>
```

Which, in my opinion, is uglier than the latter example.

So my question is - which is better?? Or is there a way to accomplish this that I'm completely unaware of?

Comment: Helper is the right place for that.

Comment: You've nailed something that's bothered me for the longest time. The fact of the matter is that probably 90% of helpers would actually be better defined on a class itself if it wasn't considered bad practice. I hope you find a good answer for this.

Comment: You might want to consider checking out [cells](http://cells.rubyforge.org/examples.html) (see an example [here](http://nicksda.apotomo.de/2010/11/lets-write-a-reusable-sidebar-component-in-rails-3/)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails is all about coding by convention. As you've pointed out, using a method in the model breaks the conventions of MVC. Unless there's a compelling reason to do so, you're better off going with the flow, and using the helper approach.

One practical issue is testing: you'll find it easier to test the helper method than the model method. Helper tests will include the `link_to` and `users_profile_path` methods for you -- model tests won't.

Finally, think of other developers reading your code. Where would they expect to find this method? If you follow MVC, you'll make their lives easier.

Answer (score 1):

Use the helper.  Because this is a method that creates a view object (the anchor tag), it's best to put it in a helper module.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ActiveRecord's to_param method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-to_param